# Is the container rebuilt at each request in Symfony 2 dev mode

Tags: symfony, ioc-container

When I am creating my own service, it looks like my object is created each time.

Service :

```
services:

  plbcache:
    class: Robusta\PlbBundle\Cache\LruCache
    arguments: [10, %timeout%, %enableCache%]
```

Class :

```
class LruCache {

  public function __construct($capacity=10, $timeout=-1, $enabled=true) {
        echo "creating the cache"; // Appear at each request
        $this->capacity = $capacity;
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
  }
}
```

Obviously, I have now problem to test if my objects are in the cache if my cache object is rebuilt each time.

For what I have understood, the service container of Symfony is a singleton and by default gives singletons - thought it can be configured for prototypes or clients sessions. So it should give me the same services objects after each request.

I have to seen in the docs that the container is rebuild in dev environment. Did I miss something, or my code is wrong ?
How to prevent dev mode from rebuilding my cache object ?

Comment: Why don't you think to use session? Every request - at least teorically - hasn't nothing to do with previous one so is mandatory and correct to rebuild an object each time. If your business logic act in another way, you should do it yourself

Comment: For what I have understood, the service container of Symfony is a singleton. So it gives the same services after each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container doesn't share instances between requests. Each request is independent but you can share some data through session (for instance). BTW all objects created during a single request are destroyed once it finishes. Next request every object need to be created again.

So while services are threated (by default but you can change the behaviour) like singleton, you should consider them a "singleton within same request". I would like to make you notice that this is a PHP behaviour and not a symfony-strictly one.

Comment: OK, like static objects are static inside the request. So using the $_SERVER variable seems a solution here ?

Comment: Nope.  As previously stated, if you want stuff to survive between requests then use sessions.  Even then the actual object does not survive.  It just gets rebuilt for each request.  Are you using the Symfony 2 framework?  If so then it already has a bunch of caching capability.

Comment: I can't add anything to Cerad comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you instantiate a class, `__construct()` is run.  Every time you run your symfony app and access your 'plbcache' class, an instance of the class will be created, thus running the `__construct()` method.  Objects are not persisted in memory between runs of PHP apps, ie a process runs and then dies each time.

If you want some data to be persisted between runs of the app, you can save them to disk or database or whatever.  If you need to have some cache building done at a certain point in time, you should probably create a method like `build()` to do it and then have code elsewhere run that when needed.  If it just has to be created once, you could have the constructor check if it has been created or run `build()` if not.